# How to sync between mongodb and elasticsearch?

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

I have a scala microservice that serves as database api, and the database I am using is mongodb.

I want to add elasticsearch that will contain all the data that my mongodb have, and I need to keep it in sync when the mongodb is updated, how can I achieve it?

what would be the best approach to do this? is there some plugins or something that can help me with this task?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [5 Different ways to synchronize data from MongoDB to ElasticSearch](https://code.likeagirl.io/5-different-ways-to-synchronize-data-from-mongodb-to-elasticsearch-d8456b83d44f), personally, I did it with Logstash where I simply filtered one collection and dumped to ES every 24 hrs, the use case is key to determine what strategy/tool is to use.